# Problem in sorting non dominated pairs of a set of points

Tags: php, function, sorting

I wrote non dominated sorting algorithm in php based on the NSGA II algorithm. The portion of the code is given below

```
function fast_non_dominated_sort($values1, $values2)
{
    
    $S= [];
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($values1); $i++)
        $S[$i]= [];

    $front=[[]];
    $n= [];
    $rank= [];

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($values1); $i++)
    {
        $n[$i]=0;
        $rank[$i]=0;
    }
    

    for($p=0;$p<sizeof($values1); $p++)
    {
        $S[$p]=[];
        $n[$p]=0;
        for($q=0;$q<sizeof($values1); $q++)
        {

            if(($values1[$p] > $values1[$q] && $values2[$p] > $values2[$q]) || ($values1[$p] >= $values1[$q] && $values2[$p] > $values2[$q]) || ($values1[$p] > $values1[$q] and $values2[$p] >= $values2[$q]))                                                                                              
                if(!in_array($q, $S[$p]))
                    array_push($S[$p], $q);


            elseif(($values1[$q] > $values1[$p] && $values2[$q] > $values2[$p]) || ($values1[$q] >= $values1[$p] && $values2[$q] > $values2[$p]) || ($values1[$q] > $values1[$p] && $values2[$q] >= $values2[$p]))
                $n[$p]=$n[$p]+1;

        }

        if($n[$p]==0)
        {
            $rank[$p]=0;
            if(!in_array($p, $front[0]))
                array_push($front[0], $p);
        }

    }
    
    
    $i=0;
    while($front[$i]!=[])
    {
        $Q=[];

        foreach($front[$i] as $p)
        {
            foreach($S[$p] as $q)
            {
                $n[$q]=$n[$q]-1;
                if($n[$q]==0)
                {
                    $rank[$q]=$i+1;
                    if(!in_array($q, $Q))
                        array_push($Q, $q);
                }   
            }
        }

        $i=$i+1;
        array_push($front, $Q);
    }

    unset($front[sizeof($front)-1]);
    return $front;
}


$x_values=[190, 180, 165, 160];
$y_values=[80, 85, 70, 22];


$result=fast_non_dominated_sort($x_values, $y_values);
```

The returned sorted points are [[0,1,2,3]]. However the result should have been [[0,1], [2], [3]]. Can anybody help me find out the bug in this code.

Any help is appreciated. For further clarifications drop a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler demonstration to express why the lack of curly braces fundamentally alters your intended conditional logic:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8Ooui))

```
$lookup = [3, 4];
$array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 1];

foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
    echo "\niteration ($i): ";
    if ($v > 1)
        if (in_array($v, $lookup))
            echo "greater than 1 and in lookup";
    
    elseif ($v < 2)
        echo "less than 2";
}

echo "\n---\n";

foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
    echo "\niteration ($i): ";
    if ($v > 1) {
        if (in_array($v, $lookup)) {
            echo "greater than 1 and in lookup";
        }
    } elseif ($v < 2) {
        echo "less than 2";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
iteration (0): 
iteration (1): 
iteration (2): greater than 1 and in lookup
iteration (3): greater than 1 and in lookup
iteration (4): 
---

iteration (0): less than 2
iteration (1): 
iteration (2): greater than 1 and in lookup
iteration (3): greater than 1 and in lookup
iteration (4): less than 2
```

Notice that your `elseif` is treated as though it is the sibling of the `if(in_array(...))` condition, despite your code tabbing expressing your desired logic to mean that it is the sibling of the parent `if()`.

**The moral of this story, never skip writing curly braces on any control structure.**  Please adopt the coding standards outlined in [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/).

---

I don't understand the required logic for your algorithm, but I will assume it is correct and refine your code to the best of my understanding.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IICAN))

```
function fast_non_dominated_sort($values1, $values2)
{
    $size = count($values1);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i) {
        $S[]= [];
        $n[] = 0;
        $rank[] = 0;
    }
    $front=[[]];

    for ($p = 0; $p < $size; ++$p) {
        for ($q = 0; $q < $size; ++$q) {
            if (($values1[$p] >= $values1[$q] && $values2[$p] > $values2[$q])
                || ($values1[$p] > $values1[$q] and $values2[$p] >= $values2[$q])
            ) {
                if (!in_array($q, $S[$p])) {
                    $S[$p][] = $q;
                }
            } elseif(($values1[$q] >= $values1[$p] && $values2[$q] > $values2[$p])
                || ($values1[$q] > $values1[$p] && $values2[$q] >= $values2[$p])
            ) {
                ++$n[$p];
            }
        }

        if (!$n[$p]) {
            $rank[$p] = 0;
            if(!in_array($p, $front[0])) {
                $front[0][] = $p;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    $i = 0;
    while ($front[$i]) {
        $Q = [];
        foreach ($front[$i] as $p) {
            foreach ($S[$p] as $q) {
                --$n[$q];
                if (!$n[$q]) {
                    $rank[$q] = $i + 1;
                    if (!in_array($q, $Q)) {
                        $Q[] = $q;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }

        ++$i;
        $front[] = $Q;
    }

    unset($front[sizeof($front) - 1]);
    return $front;
}


$x_values = [190, 180, 165, 160];
$y_values = [80, 85, 70, 22];


var_export(fast_non_dominated_sort($x_values, $y_values));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I didn't spend a huge amount of time looking at your code because the single letter variables make it harder to read AND because you said it doesn't yield what you want anyway! So... I'm not 100% sure that I understand what it is you're trying to achieve and this may be overly simplistic or simply not what you intended!*

However, this sorts the values as indicated in your expected output. Grouping the "similar" values together.

```
function evaluateDifference($a, $b){
    if(!$a || !$b){
        return false;
    }

    if(
        ($a[0] > $b[0] && $a[1] >= $b[1])
        ||
        ($a[1] > $b[1] && $a[0] >= $b[0])
    ){
        return -1;
    }

    if(
        ($b[0] > $a[0] && $b[1] >= $a[1])
        ||
        ($b[1] > $a[1] && $b[0] >= $a[0])
    ){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}

function sortPairs($x_values, $y_values){

    // Create data pairs from the input values
    $pairs = [];
    foreach($x_values as $key=>$x){
        $pairs[] = [$x, $y_values[$key]];
    }

    // Sort the pairs into order
    usort($pairs, "evaluateDifference");


    // Merge the pairs which are equal
    // We're only inserting keys here, not the actual values
    // as that is what you have shown at the end of the question
    $sorted_pairs  = [];
    $numberOfPairs = count($pairs);
    for($i = $j = 0; $i < $numberOfPairs; $i = $j){
        $sorted_pairs[$i][] = $i;
        while(evaluateDifference($pairs[$i], $pairs[++$j] ?? null) === 0){
            $sorted_pairs[$i][] = $j;
        }
    }

    return $sorted_pairs;
}

$x_values = [190, 180, 165, 160];
$y_values = [80, 85, 70, 22];


  
var_export(sortPairs($x_values, $y_values));

/*
Output:

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
  ),
)

*/
```